# How do I initialize one LiveData object to another?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

The following class has a method than can load a list of users and store it in a LiveData wrapper:

```
class UserLoader {
    ...
    val loadedUsersLiveData: MutableLiveData<List<User>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun loadUsers() {
        ...
        val userRequest: Call<UserResponse> = userApi.loadUsers()
        userRequest.enqueue(object : Callback<UserResponse> {
            ...
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserResponse>, response: Response<UserResponse>) {
               ...
              loadedUsersLiveData.value = ... // assigns the list of users returned
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

How would I initialize the LiveData variable in my class below to the value of the one that's fetched in the class above?

```
class UserTableViewModel : ViewModel() {

    // TODO: initialize usersLiveData to UserLoader's loadedUsersLiveData
    val usersLiveData: LiveData<List<User>> // ??

    fun loadUsers() {
        UserLoader().loadUsers()
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply put, the `loadUsers()` should expose the results using a Callback, and shouldn't be using LiveData for this. Then you can just assign the value to the MutableLiveData in the ViewModel, as returned by the callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserTableViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val userLoader = UserLoader()

    // TODO: initialize usersLiveData to UserLoader's loadedUsersLiveData
    val usersLiveData: LiveData<List<User>> = userLoader.loadedUsersLiveData

    fun loadUsers() {
        userLoader.loadUsers()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Don't directly expose mutable properties always expose immutable properties for reading the values.***
*on side note: you can make class `UserLoader()` to `object` if you want to safe to call it from everywhere or don't have constructor values.*

`LiveData` is an interface but what you can do is initialize it through `MutableLiveData` or another LiveData of same type which in your case from `UserLoader`.
You can do:

```
     class UserTableViewModel : ViewModel() {

        private val _userLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<User>>()
        val usersLiveData: LiveData<List<User>> get() = _userLiveData // observe it in the view..

        // don't forget to call this function...
        fun updateUserList() {
            _userLiveData.value = UserLoader().loadedUsersLiveData
        }
        
        fun loadUsers() {
            UserLoader().loadUsers()
        }
    }
```

or

```
    class UserTableViewModel : ViewModel() {
        
         //observe it in view..
        val usersLiveData: LiveData<List<User>>  = UserLoader().loadedUsersLiveData
        
    }
   
        fun loadUsers() {
            UserLoader().loadUsers()
        }
```

Comment: WIth a straightforward assignment, would usersLiveData still update observers when loadedUsersLiveData changes?  I'd tried that and it didn't seem to.

Comment: i dont know how you are calling your ``loadUser()`` function. If you really wanna use livedata with retrofit, how about using ``liveData call adapter`` or use kotlin coroutine then chain it with the livedata.